android onBackPressed button navigation crash
i want to make a back navigation logic using this code :
backBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        onBackPressed();
    });
    otherUsername.setText(otherUser.getUsername());

but it seem that the onBackPressed is deprecated now, so when i run the app and click the back button it worked for a bit but then it goes to the previous page as if i was double clicking it, and when i try to do it the second time the app will crash.
How to solve this ?
for context this is my full code :
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.daffakhairy.easychat.model.UserModel;
import com.daffakhairy.easychat.utils.AndroidUtil;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

UserModel otherUser;

EditText messageInput;
ImageButton sendMessageBtn;
ImageButton backBtn;
TextView otherUsername;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    // Get UserModel
    otherUser = AndroidUtil.getUserModelFromIntent(getIntent());

    messageInput = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_input);
    sendMessageBtn = findViewById(R.id.message_send_btn);
    backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
    otherUsername = findViewById(R.id.other_username);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_recycler_view);

    backBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        onBackPressed();
    });
    otherUsername.setText(otherUser.getUsername());

}
}


Could you please attach crash log

Here is the error in the logcat : 2024-12-26 18:20:16.824 12946-12946 AndroidRuntime com.daffakhairy.easychat E FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.daffakhairy.easychat, PID: 12946 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid

That error doesn't seem to be tied to the code you've presented. Could you include your code surrounding positionViewHolder

The onBackPressed() method has been deprecated starting with Android API level 33. The recommended approach now is to use the OnBackPressedDispatcher via the OnBackPressedCallback.
This approach allows you to handle back navigation logic more cleanly and avoid unexpected behavior.
Solution: Use OnBackPressedDispatcher
You can use the OnBackPressedCallback to handle back navigation in your activity explicitly. Below is the modified version of your code:
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
   
import com.daffakhairy.easychat.model.UserModel;
import com.daffakhairy.easychat.utils.AndroidUtil;
  
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    UserModel otherUser;

    EditText messageInput;
    ImageButton sendMessageBtn;
    ImageButton backBtn;
    TextView otherUsername;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        // Get UserModel
        otherUser = AndroidUtil.getUserModelFromIntent(getIntent());

        messageInput = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_input);
        sendMessageBtn = findViewById(R.id.message_send_btn);
        backBtn = findViewById(R.id.back_btn);
        otherUsername = findViewById(R.id.other_username);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_recycler_view);

        // Set the username
        if (otherUser != null) {
            otherUsername.setText(otherUser.getUsername());
        } else {
            otherUsername.setText("Unknown User");
        }

        // Handle back button click
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> finish()); // Directly finish the `activity

        // Handle system back button using OnBackPressedDispatcher
        OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // Custom back navigation logic
                finish(); // End the activity
            }
        };

        // Add the callback to the dispatcher
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }
}

Use OnBackPressedCallback:
Registered with the OnBackPressedDispatcher to intercept the back button press.

The back button works as expected initially. However, when I navigate to the next page for a second time and then attempt to return to the previous page by clicking the "Back" button again, the application crashes.

here is the error in the logcat : error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

The issue likely isn't directly related to onBackPressed. It's in your adapter and the data provided to it. Please post the code for your RecyclerView adapter.
Also, if you're using a ViewModel with LiveData or Rx streams providing the data to the list, that would also be helpful.

use this one
getOnBackPressedDispatcher()

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
